# How to not display data which is string if value of data null? Php

Tags: php, foreach

I won't display string if value of $post['time'] === null or  $post['time'] === ''.  Look my response https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgFMC.jpg , I  won't to show this string 'Um' and 'Uhr' if input type for date not selected(if $post['time'] === null or ''). Look my code. Main of code is this foreach loop. var_dump($message I using only for testing.

```
$message = '';
        $termini = '<p>Terminvorschlagen:</p>';

        foreach ($post['date'] as $i => $date) { 

            if($post['date'] !== NULL || $post['date'] !== '' || $post['time'] !== NULL || $post['time'] !== '') {
                $termini .= '<p>' . $i + 1 . '. ' . $date . 'um, ' . $post['time'][$i] . 'Uhr</p>';
            }
        }


        $message .= 'Name: ' . $post['name'] . '<br />';
        $message .= 'Phone: ' . $post['phone'] . '<br />';
        $message .= 'Email: ' . $post['email'] . '<br />';

        $message .= '<br />';

        $message .= 'Pneu-Typ: ' . $post['pneu'] . '<br />';
        $message .= 'Anzahl Pneus zur Montage: ' . $post['anzahl'] . '<br />';
        $message .= 'Marka: ' . $marka . '<br />';
        $message .= 'Model: ' . $model . '<br />';

        $message .= '<br />';

        $message .= $termini;
        var_dump($message);
        return;
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say, but I'll tell you this; `$post['date'] !== NULL || $post['date'] !== ''` will _always_ be true, because something that _is_ exactly one thing, is by definition _not_ exactly another thing.  So if a value _is_ `null`, then it is _not_ an empty string (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

> use `&&` instead of `||` if you want to check both the condition...

PHP `empty()` functions check if the value is `(0,"",null)`

```
  if(empty($post['date']) || empty($post['time'])) {

 $termini .= '<p>' . $i + 1 . '. ' . $date . 'um, ' . $post['time'][$i] . 'Uhr</p>';

    }
```

Comment: use && instead of || if you don't want both date and time not to be empty. for the above code...

Comment: Okey I use this but about I  got 'um' and  'Uhr'

look my code 

  foreach ($post['date'] as $i => $date) { 
   if(!empty($post['date']) && !empty($post['time'])) {
    $termini .= '<p>' . $i + 1 . '. ' . $date . 'um, ' . $post['time'][$i] . 'Uhr</p>';
       }
  }

Comment: I try but again I got same result...Again is here 'um' and 'Uhr' . If I can say if variable empty not show anythink...

Comment: print_R(post);die; before using it inside foreach loop and check [date] and [time] is empty or not... it must not be empty that is why you are getting result umm and urh

Comment: you can use die("error""); inside if(condition) to check it is working or not...

Comment: I do it. My code at in if block...but my logic is bad...I need foreach if any input type empty not show 'um' and 'Uhr' only show empty string, if $post['time'] or date here show me.... Little confused

Comment: There is enough only one field is filled and conditional is true....because my code is always true...only one input of three maybe filled and conditional is true...

Comment: just do one thing edit you question... first and clearify you problem with example
 
print_r($post) array and show it first then the result you wanted... example of it...

as you cannot clearify you question it will end up in blind guesses...

Comment: currently according to the logic if any of the value of $post array index date and time is not empty it will end up in UMM and URH... but now you are saying your logic is different so you have to explain the logic you wanting with example...

Comment: Okey this is my $post 

Array ( [pneu] => Moto[marka] => APRILIA [model] => RS4 50 [anzah4] => 1 [date] => Array ( [0] => 01/03/2019 [1] => [2] => ) [time] => Array ( [0] => 10:30 [1] => [2] => ) [accept] => on [name] => Test Test [phone] => 12345678901[email] => test@gmail.com )

Comment: according to this array date and time is not empty for each values of date and time that is why you are getting umm and urh as output...

Comment: Yes but I have Array with [0] which is filled and [1] and [2] which is empty.... I want not show 'um' and 'uhr' if any index empty...that is logic

Comment: @AlexAl okay alex I got it use the code i have updated now for you